# get value from json when passed key is a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am creating a list by fetching values from a JSON file. It is a nested JSON and the list items are- "Thriller","Fiction" which are basically keys for the next level.
on click of the item I'm passing its name(i.e. Thriller/fiction) to another function...
**var** val = thriller.

Now I need to fetch the value(i.e. "book" & bookname) corresponding to the passed key in this new function. I'm not able to do so using dot operator-
***data.library.val*** not working..

If anybody has worked on something similar..please help..

**JSON:**

```
{ "library": [

    {
        "Thriller": [
            { "book": "ABC" },
            { "book": "DEF" }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Fiction": [
            { "book": "GHI" },
            { "book": "JKL" }
        ]
    },]  }
```

**Code snippet:**

```
$.getJSON('resources/abc.json', function(data){

        var i = data.library;
        $("#menuList1").css('display','block');
        $(i).each(function(key, value){
            $.each(value, function(key, value){
                    console.log(key);
                    $("#menuList1").append('<a href="#" id="'+key+'" onClick="createSubMenu(id);">'+key+'</a>');
    });       
   });    });
```

Comment: Use variable names that do not clash with each other! Make them meaningful so you can read them and know what you are actually referencing.

Answer (score 1):

Use `data.library[key]`

[MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Member_Operators#Bracket_notation)

Answer (score 1):

Your Json is **not valid**, this `},]` specially. A good version  :

```
{
    "library": [{
        "Thriller": [{
            "book": "ABC"
        }, {
            "book": "DEF"
        }]
    }, {
        "Fiction": [{
            "book": "GHI"
        }, {
            "book": "JKL"
        }]
    }]
}
```

you can refer the website http://jsonlint.com for validating your json.